# How incite civil unrest?

Tags: society, behaviour

In order to achieve their goals nefarious agents want to incite civil unrest. This might take form of revolt, riots, other violence or labor disputes. Generally to disrupt function of civilian life as well as function of governmental bodies.  They can’t be caught (provably) doing this.

My setting Is modern society or near future.  How would they go about achieving this?

Here’s what I’ve come up with currently:

- Fund to radical fringes.  (Also supply weapons where applicable.)
- Spread propaganda

*thought*: Maybe this could be answered the other way around as well: 'what makes a stable society' and remove these parts?

Comment: That's part of your story, not really about the rules of your world

Comment: Let's add to what L.Dutch pointed out that even though there are common things which make a society (un)stable, each culture have different approaches to create (and manage) civil unrest. It'd be interesting (and more focused) to know at least which kind of country you are asking about :).

Comment: In any case, to help with your search, I suggest you look at existing revolutions and riots/protests for inspiration. If it's not to find what kind of secret actions were made, you can at the very least find what stirs people deep in their heart, and therefore deduce what will make them angry. Do note that a good chunk of revolutions/riots have front figures, even if they are backed up behind by some kind of [illuminati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati)-like organization.

Comment: Reminder to open-voters (because it's not only the close-voters's job :) ) : If you think a question is worth reopening, please state shortly why in comments, or what can be done against the closing comments. This can help a lot to reopen and helps settting a precedent for future questions :).

Comment:  You know, every user of this Stack is probably on the U.S. Homeland Security watch list just because we've hosted questions about how to create poisons, weapons of mass destruction, etc. Asking about how to actually create civil unrest in a fundamentally-contemporary context might get all our names underscored.

Comment: Also, I agree with L.Dutch and @Tortliena. You're not asking a worldbuilding question. In fact, you're basically asking a question about the choices of participants, and questions about character choices are explicitly prohibited in the [help/on-topic]. The closer the question is to a fundamental plot point or plot action, the less likely it's appropriate here.

Comment: The basic concept of how to incite civil unrest is to have massive economic troubles. When the crops fail, people depose the king. For example, if you wanted to destabilize Florida, figure out how to have a tree disease infect the orange groves such that 50-80% of the trees are ruined. Oops, that just happened in real life.

Comment: @DavidR Biosabotage. I like that.